# Dataframes - Sum some columns, get the last value from others

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I got some fantasy football data and I'm trying to sort it out so I can later apply on it, the full force of scikit-learn.

I have it on a mysql database and I got into a dataframe with pd.read_sql. All rows of the dataframe are games of a specific player and each column contains statistics such as red cards, yellow cards, assists, clean sheets, etc. This will result in multiple rows for each player , one for each game played.

My issue is that some of those stats make more sense if summed up and then divided by the number of minutes played, such as goals, assists,etc. Others, such as the name, team and value, it only makes sense to get the most recent value.

Hence, what I want to do is a new dataframe in which I have a row for each player. Some columns will be the sum of a statistic for a given player and other will be just the last value for that player.

I found a very ugly way to do this but the sums are calculated incorrectly and it is all very messy. I'm still really new to python so all help is appreciated.
What is the best way to do this?

Some of the data(just made it up but the format is the same) :

[image]

Each row is one game for a given player, Szczesny and Koscielny in this case. Columns such as minutes, goals and assists I would like to sum over all games but others, like Value and Name, I would like to retain only the last value.

The end result would be this :

[image]

Code so far :

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

mysql_conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password = 'pass',database='bpl')
#original dataframe
df_playerstats = pd.read_sql('select * from player_stats;', con=mysql_conn) 

#index of columns meant to be summed on the original data frame(df_playerstats)
column_sumidx = [3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,23] 
#index of columns not meant to be summed
column_nosumidx = [20, 18, 21, 22]

#just the column names I want on my new dataframe
column_names = ['PLAYER_NAME','MINS_PLYD','GOALS_SCORED','ASSISTS','CLEAN_SHEET','OWN_GOALS','PENALTIES_SAVED','PENALTIES_MISSED','YELLOW_CARDS','RED_CARDS','SAVES','BONUS','EA_PPI','BONUS_POINTS_SYS','NET_TRANSFERS','PLAYER_VALUE','POINTS','TEAM_NAME','POSITION','SELECTED_BY']

# this is the new dataframe, the one I wish to fill with one row per player
player_totalstats = pd.DataFrame(index = range(0,no_players),columns = column_names )
# raw dataframe with only the columns meant to be summed
playerstats_sum = df_playerstats.iloc[:,column_sumidx]
# raw dataframe with only the columns not meant to be summed
playerstats_nosum = df_playerstats.iloc[:,column_nosumidx]
for i in range(0,no_players) :
    try :
        player_totalstats.iloc[i,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,19]] = playerstats_sum[df_playerstats['PLAYER_NAME'] == player_names[i]].sum()

# I use sum with the columns not meant to be summed because I couldn't do it
#otherwise. It works because only one column is summed` `
        player_totalstats.iloc[i,[0,15,17,18]] = playerstats_nosum[df_playerstats['PLAYER_NAME'] == player_names[i]][-1:].sum()
    except:
        print 'oops' , i
        break
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample set of data and a sample desired output so we can get a better visual idea of what you are wanting to do?

Comment: Sure, just did. Let me know if need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's solution for you test data, I think you can easily apply it to your real data

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
   Mins  Goals  Ass  Value               Name
0     0      0    0    5.4  Wojciech Szczesny
1    90      0    0    5.4  Wojciech Szczesny
2     0      0    0    5.4  Wojciech Szczesny
3     0      0    0    5.4  Laurent Koscielny
4    90      0    0    5.4  Laurent Koscielny

In [17]: df.groupby('Name').agg({'Mins': np.sum, 'Goals': np.sum, 'Ass': np.sum, 'Value': lambda x: x.iloc[-1]})
Out[17]: 
                   Ass  Mins  Goals  Value
Name                                      
Laurent Koscielny    0    90      0    5.4
Wojciech Szczesny    0    90      0    5.4
```

Comment: Thanks , it's working perfectly! Definitely have to read the documentation better, I have overlooked simple (yet very effective) stuff as groupby.